# Azure Active Directory OIDC returning wrong iss claim value

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am trying to connect a [Keycloak Gatekeeper](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper) instance to AAD via Open ID Connect. To do so, I am using the `v2` endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/v2.0`.

Unfortunately even before I login there is an error in the logs:

```
unable to verify the id token   {"error": "oidc: JWT claims invalid: invalid claim value: 'iss'. expected=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/v2.0, found=https://sts.windows.net/<tenantID>/."}.
```

I did a little bit of reasearch, and found out that the `found=` value is the same as the one returned by the `v1` endpoint. This lead me to the conclusion that the application might uses the wrong version. To make sure that it is always using `v2` I've added fixed the version of the enpoint by setting `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` in my application registration manifest. Unfortunately this did also not resolve the issue.

So what do I do wrong? Or are the AAD APIs just buggy?

Comment: Can you please show the requested or API calling part to better clarity

Comment: Unfortunately not, as keycloak-gatekeeper does not log these things anywhere. But by having a look at the code I found out that it in the end just compares the value of `iss` with the `issuer`value received from `v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`. It fails because these do not match, but according to the [Specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.16.15) they would have to.

Comment: @gorootde did you ever get this working, mate? we're looking at the same thing now, running into the exact same issue.

Comment: Looks like I was able to get this working using the old endpoint:
`--discovery-url https://sts.windows.net/TENANT_ID/`